# HTML and Epoch time in img_src string

Tags: html, apache, bash, cgi

I've been looking around for a while now and need some assistance with something that seems super simple to me but just isn't as I am pretty green with HTML and scripting.

My main objective is to have epoch/unix time being updated on the link below every time the web page is served.

How can I do this within HTML (see code below)? I've also looked into writing a bash script that replaces the epoch time parameters in the file and run a cron job that edits every so often.

For example I have the following parameters in the img_src link below:

t1=1420591677&t2=1421196477

where t1=current_system_epoch_time and t2=(current_system_epoch_time - 12hrs)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<img src="http://nagiosserver/cgi-bin/nagios3/trends.cgi?createimage&t1=1420591677&t2=1421196477&assumeinitialstates=yes&assumestatesduringnotrunning=yes&initialassumedhoststate=0&initialassumedservicestate=0&assumestateretention=yes&includesoftstates=no&host=<hostname>&backtrack=8&zoom=4" >

</body>

</html>
```

If I need to explain anything further, please let me know! Thank you!

Comment: Would a cron job, as you mentioned, be acceptable to you? If the website should only be visited by you, you can call bash through javascript. If not, you can not achieve this because adding javascript in the html code would result in client side execution and the client doesn't necessarily have the ability to call unix `date '%+s'`, you could however use javascript's time `var seconds = new Date() / 1000`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

... 
<script>
   var epoch = new Date() / 1000;
   var epoch24=epoch-3600*24;
   var imgstring = //create image string concatenating strings and vars
</script> 
...
<img onload="src=imgstring">
...
 </body>

</html>
```

Or, as you stated use a server side cron job, which I would prefer.

Answer (score 0):

I really appreciate your responses! I ended up writing a bash script on my staging VM that updates the epoch time as shown below. This could probably be written better but thought I'd share. In my httpd.conf file I had to include +Includes in Options in the directory section where my html code is executed.

```
#!/bin/bash

curr=`date +%s`;
echo $curr;

neg24=$(echo "`date +%s` - 84600"| bc);
echo $neg24;

cp /var/www/html/nagios.html /root/html_backs/nagios.$curr.html
cp /root/nagios_www /root/nagios_www.bak

sed -i "s/time1/$neg24/g" /root/nagios_www
sed -i "s/time2/$curr/g" /root/nagios_www

rm -f /var/www/html/nagios.html
cp /root/nagios_www /var/www/html/nagios.html
chmod +x /var/www/html/nagios.html
mv /root/nagios_www.bak /root/nagios_www
```

nagios_www has all my HTML code except the following diff: 
t1=1420591677&t2=1421196477 is t1=time1&t2=time2

Thanks again!